# Show that the points are on the sphere

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, proof-writing

In 3-dimension space, the set of all points $\vec{r}$ where $|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}| = \frac1{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|$ happens to be a sphere.

Show that $\vec{r_3} = \frac2{3}\vec{r_1}+\frac1{3}\vec{r_2}$ and $\vec{r_4} = 2\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}$ are both on the sphere.

---

I'm not sure how to prove this. In fact, I don't think it's true. I get to

$|\vec{r_3}-\vec{r_1}| = |\frac2{3}\vec{r_1}+\frac1{3}\vec{r_2}-\vec{r_1}| = |-\frac1{3}\vec{r_1}+\frac1{3}\vec{r_2}| = \frac1{3}|-\vec{r_1}+\vec{r_2}|$ which is *not* equal to $\frac1{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|$...

Am I missing something?

Comment: For the first part, you want to show that $|\vec r_3-\vec r_1|=\frac 12|\vec r_3-\vec r_2|$. You simplified the left side, now you can do the same with the right...

Comment: Plug the same expression into $\vec r$ for the right-hand-side...

Comment: I did that and got that the right is equal to $\frac1{3}|r1-r2|$. That doesn't equal $\frac1{2}|r-r2|$ either

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}|r_1-r_2|=\frac{1}{3}|-r_1+r_2|$.

Comment: In the plane, showing that all points $r$ which satisfy $|r-r_1| = k|r-r_2|$ for some fixed $k>0, k\neq1$ is a good exercise in using the angle bisectors of triangles. Or it could probably be done with coordinate algebra, if you want to be boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true. The calculation for $|\vec{r}_{3} - \vec{r}_{1}|$ is correct:
$$|\vec{r}_{3} - \vec{r}_{1}| = |\frac{2}{3}\vec{r}_{1} + \frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{2} - \vec{r}_{2}| = |-\frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{1} + \frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{2}|.$$
The right side of the equation is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} |\vec{r}_{3} - \vec{r}_{2}| &= \frac{1}{2} |\frac{2}{3}\vec{r}_{1} + \frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{2} - \vec{r}_{2}| = \\
\frac{1}{2} |\frac{2}{3}\vec{r}_{1} - \frac{2}{3}\vec{r}_{2}| &=
\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 |\frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{1} - \frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{2}| = |\frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{1} - \frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{2}|.
\end{align}
Since $|-\frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{1} + \frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_{2}| = |\frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{1} - \frac{1}{3}\vec{r}_{2}|$ (their lengths are the same), the given condition is fulfilled. Same applies for $\vec{r}_{4}$:
$$|\vec{r}_{4} - \vec{r}_{1}| = |2\vec{r}_{1} - \vec{r}_{2} - \vec{r}_{1}| = |\vec{r}_{1} - \vec{r}_{2}|$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2} |\vec{r}_{4} - \vec{r}_{2}| = \frac{1}{2} |2\vec{r}_{1} - \vec{r}_{2} - \vec{r}_{2}| = \frac{1}{2} |2\vec{r}_{1} - 2\vec{r}_{2}| = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 |\vec{r}_{1} - \vec{r}_{2}|.$$

Answer (score 0):

You proved that:

$$|r_3-r_1|=\frac{1}{3}|r_2-r_1|$$

Now $$\frac{1}{2}|r_3-r_2|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{2}{3}r_1 -\frac{2}{3}r_2|=\frac{1}{3}|r_2-r_1|$$

Thus $|r_3-r_1|=\frac{1}{2}|r_3-r_2|$

Do the same for $r_4$

Answer (score 0):

Attempting an interpretation:

Called the circle of Appolonius  in 2 dimensions.

Rotate the circle about its diameter  and get a sphere in 3D.

The problem:

The set of points $\vec r$ with

$\star)$  $|\vec r - \vec r_1| = (1/2)| \vec r - \vec r_2| $,

where $\vec r_1,\vec r_2 $ are fixed points, is a sphere.

If $ \vec r_3,\vec r_4 $ lie on the sphere,  equation $\star)$ is

satisfied with $\vec r = \vec r_3$ and $\vec r = \vec r_4$ resp.

Check for $\vec r_3 = (2/3)\vec r_1 + (1/3)\vec r_2$.

$\star) LHS $:

$| \vec r_3 - \vec r_1| = |-(1/3)\vec r_1 +(1/3)\vec r_2|$

$= (1/3)|\vec r_1- \vec r_2|.$

$\star)$ RHS :

$(1/2) |(2/3)\vec r_1 +(1/3)\vec r_2 - \vec r_2| =$

$(1/2)|(2/3) \vec r_1 - (2/3)\vec r_2| =$

$(1/3)|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|.$

Check likewise for $ \vec r_4.$